# calling array of arrays in jsx's attribute

Tags: lodash, jsx

I have my code as below

```
  class Cell extends  React.Component{
        render(){
            return (
                <div className="cell" id={this.props.id}>{this.props.value}</div>
            )
        }
    }

    let table=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7],[1,5,8],[9,6,3],[2,4,7]];

    class Row extends React.Component{

        render(){
            return(
                <div className="row" id={this.props.id}>
                    {
                        _.map([...Array(9)],(x,i)=>
                           <Cell id={this.props.id+""+[i+1]} value={table[this.props.id][i]} key={i}/>
                         )
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    class Box extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return(
            <div className="box">
                {_.map([...Array(9)],(x,i)=>
                    <Row key={i} id={i+1}/>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to set the attribute `value` of `<Cell/>` from array `table` and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
I tried to look into the `lodash.js` file but didn't really catch what it does. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong here ?

**EDIT**: UPDATED CODE

Comment: Could you please share more code? The complete code of the component would help.

Comment: @IoannisTziligkakis I have updated my code, you can check again now

Comment: I spotted the issue in your code sample and updated my answer to properly address you issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're setting the `id` always by incrementing by one: `<Row key={i} id={i+1} />` and you use that `id` as the index for the `table`. The issue with this is that at the last iteration you'll receive a table index for a non-existing table element. This is giving you an `undefined` object.

Comment: I have an array called `table` so why it is `undefined` ?

Comment: Is it defined within the scope of the function?

Comment: so you mean that I can't call directly like this ?